# Two types of user in database how might I redesign my database?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a database in production, with two types of users. Similar to Uber, we have a 'Rider' and a 'Driver' user.

In my database, I have Users, Rider and Driver tables. The User table contains shared data between the two user types, and the Driver and Rider tables contain the remaining data.

When the database was originally designed, it was not thought that a Driver might also want to be a Rider. This use case how now arisen and I am unsure how to handle the database tables.

Currently, the email_address field has a unique constraint. The user also has a user_type field, which is either Rider or Driver.

My current thoughts are to remove the unique constraint on email_address, and create a unique index on email_address and user_type, which allows users to use both sides of the application.

This does create the problem of needing to specify which type of user is being worked with, for example, when calling /login. I think I would now need to do something like /login?type=rider.

Are there any better approaches to this? We are in production, so I can't just scrap and recreate, but I am open to migrating data if there is a better solution.

Comment: This sounds like a mess.  I would just have one table for all users, and then have a second table for user roles.  Each record in that table would have a user ID and a role ID.  In the case of users who are riders and drivers, there would be two entries in roles for a single user.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the swift reply. The user types also have additional fields, e.g. number_of_trips_taken applies to 'Riders', but not 'Drivers'.

Comment: Create a riders metadata table whose foreign key is a user ID.  If  a user does not join to this table, then you would ignore it as being not a driver.

Comment: @Rothschild Please edit the Question to clarify what you mean by “the constraint on the User table is by email_address”. If you mean Primary Key, say that.

Comment: @BasilBourque I hope that clarifies what I meant

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is a bit too big for comment, so hear me out.
Exact solution is difficult as I have not seen how you are using these tables in the application. So this solution is designed on some assumptions.

At login time, you need to determine if the user wants to logon as driver or rider. Typically, link for drivers should be different that link for users. Or there should be a flag.

For riders, you don't need additional validation. But not everyone should be allowed to log in as driver ( e.g. If a user by mistake tries to logon as driver, system should not allow that).

That means your initial user table and driver table does not need any modification. Now if you are not a driver, user role should default to rider. 
If you are a rider logging in as rider, no change is needed. 
I am assuming you have a role setting mechanism somewhere in your code base.

However, if you are a driver logging in as driver, your existing logic should continue with this additional flag, i.e. you should check if flag is present in code and only then allow checking for driver in your tables. If you are a driver coming in as rider, the flag has to go as no.

Now you have 2 options. First is to get the driver coming in as rider data from driver table only, and second is to make an entry in rider table and use that. Both approaches will work ( you will have to tweak your application logic based on the flag to get to the correct table). My suggestion will be to go to the rider table, that should reduce further complications in the system. So basically, one user, if he is a driver sometimes and rider sometimes, should have entries in both driver and rider table( assuming your constraint is only on user tables) and you should use the correct entry based on the role the person is logging in. Hopefully, once logged in using the correct table, the changes to the system would be a minimum.